# Transaction Managment Spring framework

Tags: java, spring, transactions

While learning spring framework I'm currently on the transaction management topic and while I'm not 100% against using xml I've been trying to do everything using annotations. Along comes this transaction management thing and the instructor just plops it right into the xml file and references a DataSource bean which I created with annotations

... BELOW ...

```
package com.udemy.learning.main;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.annotation.*;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("connect")
public class Connections extends BasicDataSource{

    @Value("${jdbc.user}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${jdbc.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${jdbc.driver}")
    private String driverClassName;

    @Value("${jdbc.url}")
    private String url;

    public DataSource connect() throws SQLException{
        super.setDriverClassName(this.driverClassName);
        super.setUrl(this.url);
        super.setUsername(this.username);
        super.setPassword(this.password);

        return super.createDataSource();
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void close() {
        try {
            super.close();
            System.out.println("Connection closed");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

So in an attempt to do everything with code and annotations I created a TransactionManager class and just used the @Component annotation above it. I'm sure you can imagine what that looks like so I won't drop that here, plus I'm thinking it's rather elementary looking anyway.

So anyway, long question short...

Is there a way to do this transaction management configuration the way I have attempted? rather than strictly xml? My attempt ended me up with an error like the following...

```
Bean named 'transactionManager' must be of type [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager], but was actually of type [com.udemy.learning.main.TransactionManager]
```

Comment: To get the quickest answer having the XML file you are trying to convert to Annotations copied in will go a long way. But as a further clarification are you trying to setup a connection between database and your spring application?

Comment: You need your bean to be of type `PlatformTransactionManager` so extend `PlatformTransactionManager` in your `TransactionManager` class

Comment: @James Massey you can go ahead and answer the thread if you want, because you were right. Apparently in spring 3.0 a strictly class oriented configuration method was introduced, where you simply put (at)Configuration at the top of the file and for each bean you put (at)Bean above it. Indeed one of those beans had to be of type PlatformTransactionManager, once I create this file it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need your bean to be of type `PlatformTransactionManager` so extend `PlatformTransactionManager` in your `TransactionManager` class. The exception is occuring because Spring is expecting any Transaction Manager to be a subclass of the `PlatformTransactionManager`